# How can I append Face Encodings of numpy.ndarray into List Object using python

Tags: python, encoding, numpy-ndarray

I am loading images into all_images variable and later I'm saving it into all_encodings to use it later in my code, check the code below:

```
all_images = glob.glob('images/*.jpg')

all_encodings = []

for images in all_images:
    image = fr.load_image_file(images)
    face_encode = fr.face_encodings(image)[0]

    print(face_encode)
    all_encodings = list(face_encode)
    all_encodings = list.append(face_encode)

print(all_encodings)
```

But it is throwing below error

> TypeError: descriptor 'append' requires a 'list' object but received a 'numpy.ndarray'..

Please give me the precise answer to my question. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting `all_encodings` in each iteration, guess you'd want:

```
all_images = glob.glob('images/*.jpg')

all_encodings = []

for images in all_images:
    image = fr.load_image_file(images)
    face_encode = fr.face_encodings(image)[0]

    print(face_encode)
    all_encodings.append(list(face_encode))

print(all_encodings)
```